# How to extract the dermatological and rheumatological using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

How can I extract the  string belongs to words.
here  is my text,

```
    ID  Event Name  Event Type
0   1   Taltz Seminar for Dermathologists   Out of office
2   3   Experiment Results for Taltz    In Ofice
3   4   Use of Taltz in Rheumathology   OUTOFOFFICE
5   6   RHeums Experiences with Taltz   IO
```

How can I get the Dermathologists and Rheumathology belonging string using regex.
I have tried this one.

import re

```
pattern = r'(derma\w+),\s(RHeums\w+).*'
df_named = df['Event Name'].str.extract(
                            pattern,  
                            flags=re.I)
df_clean = df_named.reindex(
                        columns = 
                            ['dermatological ', 
                             'rheumatological'])
df_clean.head()
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Convert Series to new `DataFrame`:

```
df_named = pd.DataFrame({'dermatological': df['Event Name'].str.extract('(derma\w+)', flags=re.I, expand=False),
                         'rheumatological':df['Event Name'].str.extract('(RHeuma\w+)', flags=re.I, expand=False)})


print (df_named)
    dermatological rheumatological
0  Dermathologists             NaN
1              NaN             NaN
2              NaN   Rheumathology
3              NaN             NaN
```

If need append new columns to original `DataFrame` use:

```
df_named = df.assign(dermatological = df['Event Name'].str.extract('(derma\w+)', flags=re.I),
                     rheumatological = df['Event Name'].str.extract('(RHeum\w+)', flags=re.I))


print (df_named)
   ID                         Event Name     Event Type   dermatological  \
0   1  Taltz Seminar for Dermathologists  Out of office  Dermathologists   
1   3       Experiment Results for Taltz       In Ofice              NaN   
2   4      Use of Taltz in Rheumathology    OUTOFOFFICE              NaN   
3   6      RHeums Experiences with Taltz             IO              NaN   

  rheumatological  
0             NaN  
1             NaN  
2   Rheumathology  
3          RHeums
```